# Optimal directory structure for app -- node + dojo: would this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo

I am trying to work out the best directory structure for a small Dojo application (it's a basic booking system). 
I am just about finished writing login/registration.

Here is what I have now:

```
 .

 ├── app
 │   ├── client
 │   │   ├── JsonRest.js
 │   │   ├── lib
 │   │   │   ├── defaultSubmit.js
 │   │   │   ├── globals.js
 │   │   │   ├── globalWidgets.js
 │   │   │   ├── Logger.js
 │   │   │   └── stores.js
 │   │   ├── login.js
 │   │   ├── main.css
 │   │   ├── main.js
 │   │   ├── register.js
 │   │   ├── rrl.css
 │   │   ├── TODO.txt
 │   │   ├── validators.js
 │   │   └── widgets
 │   │       ├── _AjaxValidatorMixin.js
 │   │       ├── AlertBar.js
 │   │       ├── AppMainScreen.js
 │   │       ├── BusyButton.js
 │   │       ├── css
 │   │       │   └── AlertBar.css
 │   │       ├── Dashboard.js
 │   │       ├── LoginForm.js
 │   │       ├── RegisterForm.js
 │   │       ├── SearchPage.js
 │   │       ├── StackFading.js
 │   │       ├── _StackFadingMixin.js
 │   │       ├── TabFading.js
 │   │       ├── templates
 │   │       │   ├── LoginForm.html
 │   │       │   ├── RetypePassword.html
 │   │       │   └── SearchPage.html
 │   │       ├── ValidationEmail.js
 │   │       ├── ValidationPassword.js
 │   │       ├── ValidationUsername.js
 │   │       ├── ValidationWorkspace.js
 │   └── server
 │       ├── AppErrorHandler.js
 │       ├── auth.js
 │       ├── db.js
 │       ├── globals.js
 │       ├── node_modules
 │       │   ├── express
 │       │   ├── jade
 │       │   ├── mongodb
 │       │   └── mongoose
 │       ├── public
 │       │   ├── app -> ../../client/
 │       │   └── libs -> ../../../libs
 │       ├── routes
 │       │   └── routes.js
 │       ├── server.js
 │       ├── test.js
 │       └── views
 │           ├── index.jade
 │           ├── login.jade
 │           └── register.jade
 ├── libs
     ├── build-report.txt
     ├── dojo -> dojo-1.7.1
     ├── dojo-1.7.1
     │   ├── app -> ../../app/client
     │   ├── dijit
     │   ├── dojox
     │   ├── dojo
     │   └── util
     └── dojo-1.8.0
         ├── app -> ../../app/client
         ├── dijit
         ├── dojox
         ├── dojo
         └── util
```

The idea behind it is that:

- the "app" directory will be in a git repository somewhere (it's about time I make one, actually). It has the directories "client" (all the client-side code) and "server" (the node code).
- In "libs" I will add things like dgrid, etc. I also noticed that Dojo 1.8 can be loaded within node (!). I will play with this later -- exciting!

Now, here you can see that I basically used symbolic links to make things work.

SERVER side: Under "public", I had symlinks to "app" and "libs". That way, I can access, from HTML, things like `/libs/dojo/dojox/form/resources/BusyButton.css`, or (important!) `/libs/dojo/dojo/dojo.js` and `/app/main.js` (which then instances  AppMainScreen with a simple `require(["app/widgets/AppMainScreen" ], function( AppMainScreen){ ...`

CLIENT side: I have a symlink to the latest Dojo (my boilerplate still has a problem with Dojo 1.8, so I am still using 1.7 for now). However, in order to make this work within the app:

```
require(["app/widgets/AppMainScreen" ], function( AppMainScreen){
```

I have a symlink to "app" within Dojo.

Now: I realise the basics (I *think* the symlink to "app" within Dojo is solved by simply using DojoConfig, for example). But... well, this is my current 100% unoptimised, never built tree.

I can ask you guys give me the tick of approval for this tree? Will it work once I start "building" things? (I am still miles away from doing it, but I will eventually otherwise my [pregnant] wife will go crazy!). Avoiding that symlink to "app" is one of the things I *think* I should do (but then again, do I need to?).

Thank you!

Merc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not being a fan (nor knowledgable at all) of node, it looks to me as there's a huuge javascript library :)

I'd suggest You should really consider making a buildprofile and use the prefix key to set the location of your scripts. As result of a build, you would automatically get an 'app' folder coexisting with dojo,dijit,dojox.

Actually, i would suggest that once there is a separate repository for your dojo application layer, simply do the checkout within the SDK root, e.g. :

```
wget download.dojotoolkit.org/dojotoolkit-1.7.2-src.tar.gz -O djsrc.tar.gz && tar xfz djsrc.tar.gz && rm djsrc.tar.gz
cd dojotoolkit-1.7.2-src/
svn checkout http://example/mylibrary app
sh utils/buildscripts/build.sh --profile app/package.profile --release /var/nodejs/docroot/lib/
```

There is no harm at all in developing your app.widgets somewhere else then in your main document root (/lib). You could simply setup one global variable that tells loader where to look.

If built, nothing should be nescessary, but as far as your current tree goes, try something like this

```
<script>
var isDevelopement = true;

var dojoConfig = {
  packages :  (isDevelopement) ? [ name: 'app', location: '/app/client/' ] : []
}
</script>
```